# VLC ActiveX disable subtitles

Tags: c#, winforms, activex, vlc, subtitle

I have a Windows Forms Window in my Visual Studio Project with an AxVLCPlugin2 Element from ActiveX Plugin that comes with VLC. It's working quite well but it automatically loads subtitles and displays them if a *.sub and *.idx file exist. I will never need this and would like to disable subtitles completely for the VLC ActiveX control.

```
//this is how I load and play the video into the activeX element named "axVLCPlugin21"
var convertedURI = new Uri("C:\SomeVideo.avi").AbsoluteUri;
axVLCPlugin21.playlist.clear();
axVLCPlugin21.playlist.add(convertedURI);
axVLCPlugin21.playlist.play();
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont have videos with .idx files but try:

```
if (axVLCPlugin21.subtitle.count > 0) axVLCPlugin21.subtitle.track = 0;
```

when video starts

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't apply. I can debug it and subtitle track before and after this line is 3 instead of 0. Could this be a bug in the plugin? Also tried axVLCPlugin21.video.subtitle = 0;

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 if (VLC.subtitle.count > 0)
             {
          VLC.subtitle.track = 0;                    
          VLC.video.subtitle = -1;
             }
```

It works for me :D